# VB.net Can you read the text in a certain Div

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if you read text in a certain div so when the html code says:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Main">SomeText</div>
<div id="Text">Welcome to my website</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i only want to see 'Welcome to my website' in the textbox 1.

is there anyone who knows how i can do that?

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Mark your div with runat="server":

```
<div id="TextDiv" runat="server">Welcome to my website</div>
```

then access the text in VB.NET code:

```
TextDiv.InnerHtml
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the HTML Agility pack hosted on codeplex at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/. With it you can connect to a HTML source, load the HTML into an reasonably friendly navigator and use XML type queries to traverse and manipulate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), then it's easy as:

```
Dim html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path")
Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
Dim welcomeDiv = doc.GetElementbyId("Text")
Me.TextBox1.Text = welcomeDiv.InnerText
```